# How to call result callback of async.map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I want to understand a mechanism of callbacks, so i try to compute a summary size for files in one directory. Here is my code:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import async from 'async';

export const getDirectorySize = (directory) => {
  fs.readdir(directory, (error, files) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    const counter = (el, callback) => { 
      fs.stat(path.join(directory, el), (error2, result) => {
        if (error2) throw error2;
        if (result.isFile()) callback(null, result.size);
      });
    }

    async.map(files, counter, (error3, results) => {
        if (error3) throw error3;
        console.log(results.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current, 0));
      });
    });
}
getDirectorySize('/usr/src/app');
```

So when i run code above, the third argument (callback) of async.map doesn't call. But function "counter" is called (There were no errors)!  So how to see the results of async.map?

Comment: How does this work? I'm pretty sure `async` is a reserved keyword and should not be used as a variable name

Comment: I don't know how, but it works like a module

Comment: Is `files` an array of async functions or promises?

Comment: yes, files is array

Comment: But is it an array containing async functions or promises?

Comment: this is array, with strings

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map) the second argument given to `async.map` needs to be an async function. `counter` looks to be a non-async function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239371/discussion-between-yuri-molodyko-and-evolutionxbox).